# android supportsRtl conflict, suggested to add 'tools:replace'

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, dependencies

I have an android app and i've defined `android:supportsRtl="false"` (Without it - it was rtl and I don't want it).

Now i'm using this library:

```
compile 'com.iceteck.silicompressorr:silicompressor:2.0'
```

And the my code doesn't compile:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
```

> Manifest merger failed : Attribute application@supportsRtl value=(false) from AndroidManifest.xml:40:9-36
>       is also present at [com.iceteck.silicompressorr:silicompressor:2.0] AndroidManifest.xml:17:9-35 value=(true).
>       Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:supportsRtl"' to  element at AndroidManifest.xml:36:5-189:19 to override.

I'm not completely understanding how should I implement the suggestion, or if there is another way to solve it.

I've tried `tools:replace="android:supportsRtl=false"` but it still doesn't compile

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ideally, you would use `true` for `supportsRtl`. And, ideally, the library would not be setting any value for `supportsRtl`.

However, the instructions in the error message should be straightforward:

```
Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:supportsRtl"' to element at AndroidManifest.xml:36:5-189:19 to override
```

Since we don't have your manifest, we have to guess as to what is on those lines. Most likely, you should add `tools:replace="android:supportsRtl"` to your `<application>` element, in addition to your `android:supportsRtl="false"` that you already have there.

Comment: As I said, I don't want to supportsRtl - it changes my application ui, and I don't want it. 

ok this is what I needed: 
tools:replace="android:supportsRtl"

Thanks.